# decode msgpack in redis lua

Tags: lua, redis, msgpack

```
public class MsgPackInRedis {
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private String session;
    private String protocol;
}
MsgPackInRedis msgPackStringInRedis = new MsgPackInRedis();
```

I encode a java object **msgPackStringInRedis** of class **MsgPackInRedis** with msgpack, then store in redis.
And I want to decode that in lua, which runs in redis, how can I get "**session**" ?
Can I do like this below, get session by index 3?

```
local msgPackObject = cmsgpack.unpack(msgPackStringInRedis)
local session = msgPackObject[3]
```

Comment: What's the msgpack-encoded form of your object?

Comment: `MessagePack pack = new MessagePack();`
`MsgPackInRedis msgPackStringInRedis = new MsgPackInRedis();`
`byte[] msgBytes = pack.write(msgPackStringInRedis);`

I do like this, and get msgpack-encoded byte[], which will be stored in redis.
Maybe the "byte[] msgBytes" is a value...value form, not a key-value...key-value form, I guess.
Need your help~

Comment: Please attach to your question (use the edit link) the actual byte[] contents of `msgBytes`. If you do that I'll be able show you how you can access the contents from Redis' Lua. Basically it is either by index as you tried or by name, i.e. `msgPackObject['session'])`, but that depends on what your packed message actually contains.

Comment: @Itamar Harber  Thanks for your help!   
`msgPackStringInRedis.setSession("ABCD");` 
I just put **session** value in **msgPackStringInRedis**, and pack **msgPackStringInRedis** use msgpack,and I get the **msgBytes** result:
`0x94 0xc0 0x00 0xa4 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0xc0` 
Sorry for my poor English, and I have tried in redis just now, as a result, `msgPackObject[3]` works. 
But I don't know why this work, please give me some ideal~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MessagePack is an encoding - think non-easily-readable JSON. In fact, this website does a back and forth translation between the two: http://kawanet.github.io/msgpack-lite/

Feeding your (`0x94 0xc0 0x00 0xa4 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0xc0`) to the above website, you can see the JSON representation which looks like:

```
[
  null,
  0,
  "ABCD",
  null
]
```

You can test that in Redis' Lua as well, e.g. (note that Lua 5.1 accepts *decimal* byte representation, hence the different representation of the same payload in the example):

```
$ redis-cli EVAL "return(cmsgpack.unpack('\148\192\00\164\65\66\67\68\192')[3])" 0
"ABCD"
```

So frankly, I see no issue with your code. What is the problem that you are experiencing exactly?

Comment: Thank you so much! As I was not clear what's behind msgpack, then confused by the problem. And now with your answer I Suddenly I See it.

Comment: Can you explain why this is not working `redis-cli EVAL "return cjson.encode(cmsgpack.unpack(ARGV[1]))" 0 '\148\192\00\164\65\66\67\68\192'`, but `redis-cli EVAL "return cjson.encode(cmsgpack.unpack('\148\192\00\164\65\66\67\68\192'))" 0` do works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your MessagePack-ed data is stored in the String key called `foo`, this would do your bidding:

```
EVAL "return cmsgpack.unpack(redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]))" 1 foo
```

**Note :** the above assumes that the data is serialized as arrays. Returning an object will not work as Redis' protocol doesn't support that.

Comment: Maybe I did not express my problem clearly, which is I want to just get **session** from the object, and now is solved. Thank you all the same!

Comment: @RebornTong, Also you should keep habit of upvoting the answers if you find them helpful.

Comment: Yes, I did. But is useless. As StackOverFlow feedback to me: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Ohh okay got it. I will upvote your question tomorrow as I have already reached my daily limit.

Comment: Upvoted. But still you need to ask more question or answer more questions to earn more reputations. :)

Comment: Yes, StackOverFlow is a nice website, and I am glad to communicate with you all.